# Select Frame under Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, robotframework, frame

Now I am trying to select Country Master under the common master. kindly refer below screenshot.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMebB.png)

**Code:**
***For selecting common master***

```
Select frame  leftContant
Set Focus To Element  Xpath://*[@id='theMenu']/li[1]/h3/div/a 
Click Element         Xpath://*[@id='theMenu']/li[1]/h3/div/a                 
​       Unselect Frame
     Sleep   3
```

***For Selecting country master***
**Xpath:**`//*[@id="hrefIda1b0"]`

```
 Select frame  leftContant
 Select Frame  Xpath://*[@id='hrefIda1b0']
 Frame Should Contain    Xpath://*[@id='hrefIda1b0']    Country Master    
 Select From List By Label    hrefId     Country Master
 Click Element    Xpath://*[@id='hrefIda1b0']
```

But code is not executing for selection of country master even no issue is coming in the output.

I have tried by Select but it's not selecting the country master. It's also not showing any issue in the output.